# pickerView on tableViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a UITableViewController and i'm trying to put a UIPicker over it.

I made a button that calls this method:

```
-(void)editTimeClicked:(UIButton *)button{

    PickerViewController *pickerVC = [[PickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickerViewController" bundle:nil];

    UIView *pickerView = pickerVC.view;
    pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 216);
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
}
```

After I call it the picker is sitting where I want it to - everything is perfect until now.

But when I try to scroll the picker, the app crashes.

I don't have a delegate method that runs on scroll… what could it be?

Comment: have you implemented datasource  & delegate methods of picker ?

Comment: Yes, in the .h of the picker nib file

Comment: what is the crash log ?

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Add  `<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>` in your `.h file` 
and also give `delegate and datasource of UIPickerView` as self such like,

```
pickerView.delegate = self; 
pickerView.dataSource = self;
```

And Implement relavent methods of `delegate and datasource of UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, didn't use the picker from another nib but created it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

No need for different xib for this.

Try this ::

In .h File

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIPickerView *pickerView;
```

In .m file

```
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;

......

[self.tableView addSubview:pickerView];
```

Picker View Methods ::

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView1 didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
}

-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView1 viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
}
```

Hope, you understand.

Thanks.